# Nginx as reverse proxy in Opneshift

Tags: nginx, openshift, config, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I am new to `Nginx` and I could validate some of the `reverse proxy scenarios` in `Windows and Ubuntu machine` successfully. However I am facing challenges on validating them on `Openshift` cluster platform.

I am new to `Docker/Kubernetes/Openshift`. I am able to deploy the below `Nginx` image in `Openshift` and hit the welcome page url successfully.

"https://github.com/sclorg/nginx-ex"

Now I want to achieve the below things on the image.

1. Want to know what is the nginx version deployed on the above image.
2. Want to customize the nginx.conf file frequently and update my container with the latest changes.
3. Want to use the latest version of nginx.
4. Want to know how to locate the nginx.conf file and other nginx files deployed through the above image.
5. When I open a POD terminal, I can see Nginx 1.12 files are deployed in /etc/nginx, can I upgrade this to latest version? are these files created by the deployment of the above image?

Please clarify & help me on the above queries.

Answer (score 0):

We'll be glad assisting you with these questions, however you'll need to get a better understanding of how containers and Kubernetes works for all the information below to be helpful to you.

```
Want to know what is the nginx version deployed on the above image.
```

When you deployed your NGINX using the `oc new-app centos/nginx-112-centos7~https://github.com/sclorg/nginx-ex` command in the repository, you are using the `centos/nginx-112-centos7` image, which is NGINX 1.12. Note that you can also deploy NGINX with the image `centos/nginx-116-centos7`.

```
Want to customize the nginx.conf file frequently and update my container with the latest changes.
```

You should look into how [ConfigMaps](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/configmaps.html) work to inject your own `nginx.conf` into the container.

```
Want to use the latest version of nginx.
```

The latest version for the image you are currently using is 1.16, as written above. If you want to use a newer version, you may need to use the `nginx` image: https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx

```
Want to know how to locate the nginx.conf file and other nginx files deployed through the above image.
```

You can use `oc rsh <podname>` to access your Pod and see what files are deployed in your container.

```
When I open a POD terminal, I can see Nginx 1.12 files are deployed in /etc/nginx, can I upgrade this to latest version? are these files created by the deployment of the above image?
```

As written above, you'll need to use another container image.